# How to use @DataProvider present in different class

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testng, dataprovider, testng-dataprovider

How to use `@DataProvider` that is present in a different class?

I have created a different package and I have defined data providers next to each test cases.  Please share how I may to use that in a different class.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `dataProviderClass` attribute of `@Test`:

```
public class StaticProvider {
  @DataProvider(name = "create")
  public static Object[][] createData() {
    return new Object[][] {
      new Object[] { new Integer(42) }
    };
  }
}

public class MyTest {
  @Test(dataProvider = "create", dataProviderClass = StaticProvider.class)
  public void test(Integer n) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Check [the documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders) for more details.

Comment: The only thing worth extra mentioning is that: "If you want to put your data provider in a different class, it needs to be a static method or a class with a non-arg constructor(...)", so it does not have to be static.

Comment: @juherr: what happens if there are more than one dataproviders in the same class?

Comment: I suppose in your answer you mean `dataProvider = "createData"`

Comment: A data provider is defined by its name. Here, "create".

Comment: @kushal - Not required. It can be "create" alone

Answer (score 0):

If you have unique dataProvider method name (createData), and if you choose not to give name after DataProvider annotation as below,

```
@DataProvider    
public Object[][] createData(){

}
```

Then you can use the method name as below,

```
@Test(dataProvider = "createData", dataProviderClass = StaticProvider.class)
```